# How to create a new custom object record using VisualForce page and Javascript

Tags: visualforce

**Problem**
I am currently working on developing an action for use in Salesforce1 to create a new record of a custom object using a visualforce page and javascript. I'm fairly new to this and can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong anywhere...

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" title="Create Location">     
    <apex:remoteObjects >
        <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Location__c" fields="Id,VIN__c"/>
    </apex:remoteObjects>    

    <div class="mypage">
        VIN:
        <input type="text" id="myVIN"/>
        <button onclick="createLocation()">Create Location</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        function createLocation() {
        var myVIN = document.getElementById("myVIN");
        var location = new sforce.SObject("Location__c");
        location.create({VIN__c: myVIN});
        }
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

My custom object is Location__c. The it's only custom field is VIN__c, which is required to be input on record creation.

I'm guessing something is going wrong in the createLocation() js function but I'm not too sure. All the examples I could find only work with standard salesforce objects.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are assigning the entire `myVIN` DOM node to the field instead of extracting its *value*. The last line of your `createLocation()` function should read:
`location.create({VIN__c: myVIN.value});`

Comment: that makes sense but it's still not working.. I do need to include the __c on VIN correct? Is there anything else I need in location.create()?

Comment: I figured it out, I changed new sforce.Sobject("Location__c") to new sObjectModel.Location__c()